# Recursive function to subtract

Tags: c, recursion, computer-science, function-definition

This function gets a sequence of numbers until the user inputs `-1`. It should return the sum of the numbers at the `index(mod3)=0` minus the number in the other indexes.

For example:

```
9 2 4 7 8 1 3 -1
```

the function sums at first all the numbers that are at the indexes that divisible by three. So `sum1` supposed to be `5` because 4 is at the 3rd index and 1 is at the 6th index, all the other indexes sum up to `sum2`. Then it should subtract one from another : `sum1 - sum2` and the output should be `-24` (*i.e.,* sum1 - sum2 = 5 - 29 = -24)

I wrote this code and I don't understand why it doesn't work properly the output that is returned for every sequence is 0.

```
int sumOfSeq();
void main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sumOfSeq());
    system("pause");
}
int sumOfSeq()
{
    int n, curr = 1, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == -1)
        return sum1 - sum2;
    else
    {
        if (curr % 3 == 0)
        {
            sum1 += n;
            curr++;
        }
        else
        {
            sum2 += n;
            curr++;
        }
        sumOfSeq();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the function `sumOfSeq` you are not using the sum obtained by next recursive calls of the function. You are just calling within the function

```
sumOfSeq();
```

So the function does not make a sense.

And there is no need to calculate two sums separately because in any case the function has to return one value, the result sum.

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int sumOfSeq( size_t n )
{
    long long int sum = 0;
    
    int item;
    
    if ( scanf( "%d", &item ) == 1 && item != -1 )
    {
        sum += sumOfSeq( n + 1 ) + ( ( n + 1 ) % 3 == 0 ? item : -item );
    }
    
    return sum;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%lld\n", sumOfSeq( 0 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output for the inputted sequence of numbers

```
9 2 4 7 8 1 3 -1
```

is

```
-24
```

As you can see the function definition is enough simple and the function uses only one parameter.

Bear in mind that it is a bad idea to use static local variables if the function can be written without them. Otherwise you will have some difficulties running the function for a second time.

Also pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

instead of

```
void main()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote this code and don't understand why it doesn't work properly
> the output that is returned for every sequence is 0.

It returns `0` because the variables `curr`, `sum1`, and `sum2` are initialized with `0` at the beginning of each recursive call of the method `sumOfSeq`:

```
 int n, curr = 1, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
```

Instead, you need to pass the most updated value of those variables on each recursive call, something as follows:

```
int sumOfSeq(int curr, int sum1, int sum2);
void main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sumOfSeq(1, 0, 0));
    system("pause");
}
int sumOfSeq(int curr, int sum1, int sum2)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == -1)
         return sum1 - sum2;
    else if (curr % 3 == 0)
         return sumOfSeq(curr + 1, sum1 + n, sum2);
    else
         return sumOfSeq(curr + 1, sum1, sum2 + n);
}
```

In this manner, when you reach the recursion stopping condition, namely

```
if (n == -1)
   return sum1 - sum2;
```

the variables `sum1` and `sum2` will be the result of having added the 'n's over all those recursive calls.

One can shorten the function with the ternary operator

```
int sumOfSeq(int curr, int sum1, int sum2)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == -1)
        return sum2 - sum1;

    return (curr % 3 == 0) ? sumOfSeq(curr + 1, sum1 + n, sum2) : 
                             sumOfSeq(curr + 1, sum1, sum2 + n);
}
```